Package for calculating ADM mass for a given asymptotically flat metric tensor
I am asking for Mathematica package, such that for the input of an asymptotically flat Lorentzian metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ it will give the ADM mass of the object that creates the corresponding gravitational field.
Theoretically the ADM mass given by the following formula:
$$M_{ADM}=\oint_\infty\sqrt{g}g^{ij}g^{kl}(g_{ik,j}-g_{ij,k})dS_{l}$$
Where for D dimensional space the integration is over the $D-2$ hypersphere with infinite radius.

xAct (http://xact.es/) is often used in general relativity calculation and tensor manipulation applications, but I am not sure it can calculate ADM mass.
